# Test for connection to the internet in a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, internet-connection

I'm writing a script to test our internet connection periodically and can't figure out how to write an if statement that doesn't cause powershell to fail on error, or return a true/false from Test-Connection or Test-NetConnection to a specific ip address.

I've tried

```
    if(Test-NetConnection 192.168.1.222) { echo "OK"} else {echo "Not OK"}
```

That always returns OK.

Can a text be done that returns a true/false result that can be used in a conditional expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test-NetConnection` without specifying a `-Port` is essentially an icmp echo request, if you're just testing this then probably would be better to use just `Test-Connection`. Solution is to use:

- `-InformationLevel Quiet` for `Test-NetConnection`:

```bash
if (Test-NetConnection 192.168.1.222 -InformationLevel Quiet) {
    # OK here
}
else {
    # Bad here
}
```

- `-Quiet` for `Test-Connection`:

```bash
if (Test-Connection 192.168.1.222 -Quiet) {
    # OK here
}
else {
    # Bad here
}
```

Reason why your condition always evaluates to `$true` is because `Test-NetConnection` outputs an object no matter if failed or not:

```bash
PS ..pwsh\> Test-NetConnection doesnotexist.xyz

WARNING: Name resolution of doesnotexist.xyz failed

ComputerName   : doesnotexist.xyz
RemoteAddress  : 
InterfaceAlias : 
SourceAddress  : 
PingSucceeded  : False
```

And objects when coerced to a `bool` always evaluate to `true`:

```bash
PS ..pwsh\> [bool] (Test-NetConnection doesnotexist.xyz)

WARNING: Name resolution of doesnotexist.xyz failed
True
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, great answer, and especially about the info on getting a proper boolean response.